# Queue object remains empty when items queued onto it

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, linked-list, queue

I have two classes, `Club` and `party`. `Club` `extends`a generic `Queue<E>`and implements  an `fitnessInterface`.

`Queue<E> implements QueueInterface<E>`

**Club**

```
public class Club extends Queue<Bachelor> implements fitnessInterface{

   protected Queue<Bachelor> bachelorQ;

   public Club(){
       super();

       bachelorQ = new Queue<Bachelor>();
    }

public boolean Eligible(Bachelor bachelor){

       if(bachelor==null){throw new NullPointerException();}

       return true;
     }

@Override
public QueueInterface<Bachelor> enqueue(Bachelor bachelor){

       if(bachelor==null){
             throw new NullPointerException();
       else{
             bachelorQ.enqueue(bachelor); }

       return this; //the class queue
    }
}
```

**Party**

```
public class Party extends Club{
       super();
    }

@Override
public boolean Eligible(Bachelor bachelor){

   if(bachelor==null){throw new NullPointerException();}

   if(bachelor.getPushups()>=25){return true;}

   return false;

   }
}
```

The `Bachelor` class extends the `QueueInterface` and has a constructor that takes in an `Integer`as the argument and has, among others, a `getPushUps()` method.

The problem is when I create a `Party` object and try to enqueue Bachelors ralph or charlie, it remains empty.

My generic Queue class works perfect. It has `dequeue` , `enqueue`, `isEmpty`, `peek`, `size` and `toString` methods. All work fine.

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     Party bigParty = new Party();

     Bachelor jack,charlie,ralph;

     jack = new Bachelor(15);
     ralph = new Bachelor(27);
     charlie = new Bachelor(39);

     //Eligibility tests
     System.out.println(bigParty.Eligible(charlie));
     System.out.println(bigParty.Eligible(ralph));
     System.out.println(bigParty.Eligible(jack));

     System.out.println(bigParty.enqueue(ralph));
     System.out.println(bigParty.enqueue(charlie));
     System.out.println(bigParty.size());
     System.out.println(bigParty.bachelorQ.size());
}
```

**Ouput**

```
true
true
false
[]
[]
0
2
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you mixup both inheritance and composition. Check this method:

```
@Override
public QueueInterface<Bachelor> enqueue(Bachelor bachelor){

       if(bachelor==null){
             throw new NullPointerException();

       bachelorQ.enqueue(bachelor); 

       return this; //the class queue
    }
}
```

You're invoking `enqueue()` on `bachelorQ`, but returning `this`. Both are different references, pointing to different objects.

Either you should return `bachelorQ`, or just invoke `super.enqueue(bachelor)`.

BTW, since you're already extending `Queue<Bachelor>`, I don't see the need of `bachelorQ` reference there. You can just remove it. Or even better, just don't extend from `Queue<Bachelor>`. You should prefer composition over inheritance whereever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything Rohit Jain said. However, you have an additional problem here. In your enqueue method you have wrapped the contents in the `if(bachelor==null)` block. Therefore, bachelorQ only enqueues the bachelor if the bachelor is null. I assume this is not how you intend for it to work.

```
@Override
public QueueInterface<Bachelor> enqueue(Bachelor bachelor){

       if(bachelor==null){
             throw new NullPointerException();

       bachelorQ.enqueue(bachelor); 

       return this; //the class queue
    }
}
```

I recommend you rewriting your Club class to look something more like this:

```
public class Club implements fitnessInterface
{
    protected Queue<Bachelor> bachelors;

    public Club(){
        super();
        bachelors = new Queue<Bachelor>();
    }

    public boolean Eligible(Bachelor bachelor)
    {
        if(bachelor==null) throw new NullPointerException();
        return true;
     }

    @Override
    public QueueInterface<Bachelor> enqueue(Bachelor bachelor)
    {
        if(bachelor==null) throw new NullPointerException();
        bachelors.enqueue(bachelor); 
        return bachelors;
    }
}
```